# UICollectionViewFlowLayout for self-sizing, full-width items: incorrect y position

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to implement a collection view, in which items have:

- automatic height based on constraints
- the full available width of the collection view.

I'm aware that this is pretty easy to accomplish `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, but I'm looking to solve it for iOS 11+. I've decided to implement a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```swift
class SingleColumnFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView,
              let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return [] }
        
        layoutAttributes
            .filter { $0.representedElementCategory == .cell }
            .forEach { attributes in
                let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds
                    .inset(by: collectionView.contentInset)
                    .width
                
                attributes.frame.origin.x = sectionInset.left
                attributes.frame.size.width = availableWidth
            }
        
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

The result isn't quite what I have imagined:

[image: incorrect y]

The cell I'm using is pretty simple:

[image]

Interestingly if I add a fixed width constraint to the label, it works correctly, so my theory is that

- for some reason the collection view fails to infer the width of the label correctly
- for that reason, it thinks that it can fit multiple items in the same row
- because of this, it calculates incorrect `y` values for some of the items.

I would like to make this work without fixed-width labels, so my question would be: am I missing anything obvious? Is there a way to fix this?

For anyone interested, I've uploaded the entire project to [GitHub](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/ContextMenuDemo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was caused by the fixed trailing constraint of the label. The label's intrinsic width was smaller (due to short text), and since the entire cell was constrained horizontally, the cell width also became small. I fixed it by changing the trailing constraint from 'equal' to 'greater than'.

[image: constraint]